# How can I sort data entries so that a range of data is grouped together in Python, or Google Sheets?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, google-sheets

For instance, given a dataset of various weights and names, how can I group individuals with similar weights (+/- 5% the weight I want) together?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi @AlbertLee! I don't understand in which code language or software you want your answer. Could you please clarify that so I can help you better?

Comment: HI @Jacques-GuzelHeron! Ideally, I would like to be able to do this on Google Sheets, but if that is not possible, could you help me with this in terms of Python? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you want to divide your data in groups where the maximum difference from the biggest to the smaller is ±5%. I wrote an [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) code that can do that in your Sheet.  First, I wrote an example Sheet with student names and test scores (from 0 to 10) instead of names and heights; I'll explain why later. This is the initial state of the example sheet:

[image: Initial example]

In the `Group` column the code will drop the group ID as an integer starting at 0. This is the code:

```js
function so62060595() {
  var dataColumn = 2; // Column B
  var groupColumn = 3; // Column C
  var dataSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = dataSheet.getRange(2, 1, dataSheet.getLastRow() - 1, dataSheet
    .getLastColumn()).sort({
    column: dataColumn,
    ascending: false
  });
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var groupingPercentage = 5 / 100 // 5%
  var upperBound = data[0][dataColumn - 1];
  var groupID = 0;

  for (var r = 0; r < data.length; r++) {
    if (upperBound - upperBound * groupingPercentage <= data[r][dataColumn -
      1] + data[r][dataColumn - 1] * groupingPercentage) {
      // Include in the same group
      data[r][groupColumn - 1] = groupID;
    } else {
      // Create a new group
      var groupID = groupID + 1;
      var upperBound = data[r][dataColumn - 1];

      data[r][groupColumn - 1] = groupID;
    }
  }

  dataRange.setValues(data);
}
```

The first thing that the code does is to open the sheet with [`SpreadsheetApp.getActive()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactive), [`Spreadsheet.getActiveSheet()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getactivesheet). After that, the code looks for the data range with [`Sheet.getRange()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns) (notice how it uses [`Sheet.getLastRow()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow) and [`Sheet.getLastColumn()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastcolumn) to find the range size) and sorts it with [`Range.sort()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#sortcolumnposition,-ascending) using the score column as a reference. Later, it reads the range with [`Range.getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues). Also, I initialized some variables like the ID and group columns, the desired grouping percentage (5%) in this case and the initial group ID (`0`).

After all that initialization the code will iterate over every row and check if the data value (`Score` in the example) is at a ±5% of distance to the upper bound of the group (the highest value in the group). If the value is in the ±5% range, the group ID will be dropped. If it's not in the range, a new group ID will be generated and the upper bound taken from that entry. The process will continue until all entries have a group ID, and after that the data will be entered in the table with [`Range.setValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues). The final result looks like this:

[image: Final example]

And now, why did I use test scores instead of heights? Well, look what happens with an example of heights using the previous code:

[image: Heights example]

Only two groups are generated (`0` and `1`) because the distance between realistic heights is smaller than ±5%. I hope that my answer helps you, but don't hesitate to ask me any additional doubt.

---

## UPDATE

Based on the question update in your comment I modified the script. If I understand correctly, you want a midpoint in each group and calculate the group bounds based on that midpoint plus/minus 5%. If my assumption is correct, you can use the following code:

```js
function calculateGroupBounds(groupingPercentage, groupUpperBound) {
  var groupBounds = {};
  groupBounds['groupUpperBound'] = groupUpperBound;
  groupBounds['groupMidpoint'] = 100 * groupUpperBound / (100 +
    groupingPercentage);
  groupBounds['groupLowerBound'] = (100 - groupingPercentage) * groupBounds[
    'groupMidpoint'] / 100;

  return groupBounds;
}

function so62060595B() {
  // Sheet reading
  var dataColumn = 2; // Column B
  var groupColumn = 3; // Column C
  var dataSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = dataSheet.getRange(2, 1, dataSheet.getLastRow() - 1, dataSheet
    .getLastColumn()).sort({
    column: dataColumn,
    ascending: false
  });
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  // Group initialization
  var groupingPercentage = 5; // 5%
  var groupID = 0;
  var groupUpperBound = data[0][dataColumn - 1];
  var groupBounds = calculateGroupBounds(groupingPercentage, groupUpperBound)
  var groupMidpoint = groupBounds['groupMidpoint'];
  var groupLowerBound = groupBounds['groupLowerBound'];

  for (var r = 0; r < data.length; r++) {
    if (data[r][dataColumn - 1] <= groupUpperBound && data[r][dataColumn - 1] >=
      groupLowerBound) {
      // Include in the same group
      data[r][groupColumn - 1] = groupID;
    } else {
      // Create a new group
      var groupID = groupID + 1;
      var upperBound = data[r][dataColumn - 1];
      var groupBounds = calculateGroupBounds(groupingPercentage,
        upperBound)
      var groupMidpoint = groupBounds['groupMidpoint'];
      var groupLowerBound = groupBounds['groupLowerBound'];

      data[r][groupColumn - 1] = groupID;
    }
  }

  dataRange.setValues(data);
}
```

This new code uses the same Apps Script methods as the previous one and includes a new function (`calculateGroupBounds()`) to compute the upper and lower bounds and the midpoint. In the data iteration the code will check if the value falls between the upper and lower bound, and if it does the group iD will be dropped. If it doesn't a new group will be created. This is the result with the same example data as the previous code:

[image: Scores example using Code II]

And this is the result with the heights table:

[image: Heights example using Code II]

These results are the same as the previous code even though we use a different approach in this second code. This is because on the first code I used mathematical properties to divide the data in ±5% groups without calculating the midpoint. Please, ask me any doubts if you still need help.

Comment: This leads me in the right direction, but lets say instead I wanted to set a value and group data so that it is ±5% of that value. I was thinking something like the following:
 var input_weight = 145 
  var groupingPercentage = 5 / 100 // 5% 
  var upperBound = input_weight+input_weight*groupingPercentage;
  var lowerBound= input_weight-input_weight*groupingPercentage;

Comment: @AlbertLee I updated my answer based on your new requirements. Please, take a look and ask me any doubts.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use package. For excel, openpyxl is such essential package in python. You can do sort, data entry, making chart on excel by using this package in python. First, go to this link.

https://pypi.org/
search openpyxl and install this package.

https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#create-a-workbook 
this link is for guideline to use openpyxl.